# How to Start a Thread on a Bool Method Inside a Conditional?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
bool isTrue()
{
    return true
}

int main ()
{
    if (isTrue())
    {
         // Do something
    }
}
```

I realize that this sample code makes no sense, but the logic isn't what is important, just trying to set it up for the question.  How can I call a thread on isTrue()?  Typically, I would use std::thread t(//insert function here), but that can't be done here, as thread doesn't return a bool.  Is there any decent way to do this?  I'm fairly new with threads and such, so I could easily be not understanding something fundamental.

Comment: `How to Start a Thread on a Bool Method Inside a Conditional?` That's a bit confusing. I think what you actually ask is: `How to return from a thread?`

Comment: std::async with std::future may be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as thread doesn't return a bool. Is there any decent way to do this?

std::async is a very handy way of starting a task asynchronously. It will store the returned result in a "shared state" so that we can obtain it later (when it's ready)

To start an asynchronous task that runs `isTrue()` on the background, we call (and the result can be accessed through fut later)

```
std::future<bool> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, isTrue);
```

To obtain the result when we need it(i.e. in the if condition), we would call

```
bool result = fut.get();
```

Then you can use it in the if statement.

```
if (result)
{
     // Do something
}
```

And you can basically pass any kinds of function into std::async and store the result result in the associated std::future.

Comment: I think you guessed what was being asked.  Would it be more idiomatic to have `if ( fut.get() )`?  That is, ask for the result when the result is needed?

Comment: Yes, I would think so. if ( fut.get()) is more appropriate in this case, and certainly no need for another variable just to store a bool here :). I was trying to provide a more general case. i.e. since std::future::get() can only be called once, sometimes we'd want to store the result if we need to use it multiple times later.

Comment: Just curious as to why fut.get() can only be called once.  Any good explanation of it?  Thanks.

Comment: You’d need C++11 for future. Does your compiler not support C++11?

Comment: @joe_04_04 new question!  :)

Comment: Because the “shared state” will be released after get(). There is another thing called shared_future which will allow multiple calls of get...